# MinMaxScaler returns same value for single input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data frame as shown below and I used Scikit-Learn's `MinMaxScaler` to normalize the values of the `path_len` column between zero and one.

First three rows of my dataframe before:

```
feature_1, feature_2, path_len
        0          1        10
        1          1        16
        0          0        117
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
min_max = MinMaxScaler()
features['path_len'] = min_max.fit_transform(features[['path_len']])
```

First three rows of my dataframe after:

```
feature_1, feature_2, path_len
        0          1  0.033582
        1          1  0.055970
        0          0  0.432836
```

When I then try to use  `min_max.transform()` on a new input value for `path_len`, I get the same exact value:

```
def preprocess_input(link, min_max, features):
 
    df = pd.DataFrame( columns=features.columns)
    df['feature_1'] = ...
    df['feature_2'] = ...
    df['path_len'] = 86 #arbitrary number
    df['path_len'] = min_max.transform(df[['path_len']]) ### right here!
    return df
```

The final value in `df['path_len']` is `86` again!

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: It seems you forget `fit_transform` instead `transform`, else I got `NotFittedError: This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.`

Comment: I use **fit_transform** with the training data on the path_len column, then I pass the scaler to the function and use **transform** on new input and I get the result I stated above. The aim here is to preprocess new input before passing it to the machine learning model.

Comment: This way is supposed to be the right way for transforming ur data, since u didn't provide the full code, i assume there is some problem with the call of function & saving the output, U can try ur code without calling the function and share the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line:

```
features['path_len'] = min_max.fit_transform(features[['path_len']])
```

to:

```
min_max.fit(features[['path_len']])
features['path_len'] = min_max.transform(features[['path_len']])
```

and your code will work in full as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fit the `scaler` object again, you can do de following:

```py
scaled_value = (value_in_original_scale - scaler.data_min_[i]) * scaler.scale_[i]
```

Where `i` is the column index that you want to transform.